# Bash Find Files with zero size and delete files with different extensions

Tags: bash, find

This command will find files of zero size:

```
find . -size 0
```

A filename returned might be

```
filename.001
```

I am looking for a one liner that will delete files found with this, plus any that have the same filename with a different extension (which would be non-zero sized), so these files would be deleted too:

```
filename.txt
filename.bak
filename.ZZz
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$> find . -size 0 | while read f; do rm "${f%.*}."* ; done
```

explanation:

1. find all files with size 0
2. pipe the names to the while loop
3. cut of the suffix (extension) part `${f%.*}` (read `man bash`)
4. `rm` all other files with the same base

Comment: Great, I was trying to get the suffix cutting working in `-exec` with `find` but this way is easier.